# Quick question on convolution - Diffraction through a pair of slits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, double-slit-experiment, fourier-transform, diffraction

We know that the fourier transform of the amplitude function (in terms of $y$) gives you the amplitude function (in terms of $\theta$)

Consider a pair of triangular slits:

[image]

Fourier transform of G(y) is:
$$FT[G_{(y)}] = G_{(\theta)} = e^{-i\beta a} sinc \left( \frac{\beta a}{2}\right) cos\left( \frac{\beta a}{2}\right)$$

Fourier transform of H(y) is:
$$FT[H_{(y)}] = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{i\beta a}{2}} sinc \left(\frac{\beta a}{2} \right) $$

Since $T = G \otimes H$, it implies that $FT[T_{(x)}] = FT[G_{(x)}] \cdot FT[H_{(x)}] $

Thus in terms of $\theta$:
$$ G_{(\theta)} =  \frac{1}{2} e^{-i\beta a} sinc \left( \frac{\beta a}{2}\right) cos\left( \frac{\beta a}{2}\right)   e^{-\frac{i\beta a}{2}} sinc \left(\frac{\beta a}{2} \right) $$

Thus the intensity is:
$$G \propto |G_{(\theta)}|^2 = I_0  sinc^4 \left( \frac{\beta a}{2}\right) cos ^2 \left( \frac{\beta a}{2}\right) $$

This makes sense because for a double rectangular slit, due to its non-zero width, the envelope falls as $\propto sinc^2 \left(\frac{\beta a}{2} \right)$. Now the triangular slit has **half the area** of the rectangular slit, so we would expect the envelope to fall even faster. In fourier space, factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ the area is brought up to the power, giving $\propto \left( sinc^2 \left(\frac{\beta a}{2} \right) \right)^2$

Does this make sense?